# How to send firebase data to slack using cloud functions?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, slack, google-cloud-functions

I cloned this sample [minimal-webhook](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/minimal-webhook) and got this working. I wanted to extend this functionality by sending the writes to slack.

I am using the incoming webhook of slack. I guess the issue is the way how I add the data payload in nodejs. Can anyone help? Thanks in advance. Attached my code and error log from firebase.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const request = require('request-promise');
const WEBHOOK_URL = 'https://hooks.slack.com/services/abc'
var headers = {
    'Content-type': 'application/json'
};
exports.webhook = functions.database.ref('/hooks/{hookId}').onWrite(event => {
  return request({
    uri: WEBHOOK_URL,
    method: 'POST',
    headers: headers,
     body: event.data.toJSON,
    resolveWithFullResponse: true
  }).then(response => {
    if (response.statusCode >= 400) {
      throw new Error(`HTTP Error: ${response.statusCode}`);
    }
    console.log('SUCCESS! Posted', event.data.ref);
  });
});`
```

[image: Also attached the error log from Firebase]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[@Bob Snyder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44192671/3068190) is on the right track. However Slack expects certain things when you use web hooks.

When you send a POST request to the webhook, the following conditions need to be met:

- `Content-Type` must be `application/json`
- The request body must be properly formatted JSON.
- The request body must contain one of the following fields: `text`, `fallback` or `attachments`.

Now, when you store data on firebase, you could store all the information you need in the database, or you can just keep the common stuff in your code and only put the payload (the data you want to send) in the database.

The following snippet of code will allow you to store whatever you want at the specified location in the database. The data stored there will be transmitted as the text parameter of the web hook in JSON format.

```
exports.webhook = functions.database.ref('/hooks/{hookId}').onWrite(event => {
  var body = {
    "channel": "#general",
    "username": "your-bot-name-here",
    "icon_emoji": ":computer:",
    "text": event.data.toJSON()
  };

  return request({
    uri: WEBHOOK_URL,
    method: 'POST',
    body: body,
    json: true,
    resolveWithFullResponse: true
  }).then(response => {
    if (response.statusCode >= 400) {
      throw new Error(`HTTP Error: ${response.statusCode}`);
    }
    console.log('SUCCESS! Posted', event.data.ref);
  });
});
```

*Note:* The function `toJSON()` is added by the `DataSnapshot` class of Firebase (which `event.data` is an instance of). If using a different object, the same result can be achieved using `JSON.stringify(obj)`.

You should also consider checking the type of `onWrite()` event. There's no point in sending a request to Slack when the data was deleted (use `if (!event.data.exists()) { /* data was deleted */ return; }`) and you may also want to only send the request once (use `if (event.data.previous.exists()) { /* data has been updated */ return; }`).

If you wish to make the message look nicer, you can find information on formatting the `text` field at https://api.slack.com/docs/messages/builder

Answer (score 1):

Use `body: event.data.val()` instead of `body: event.data.toJSON`.  You also need `json: true`.  Add a `catch()` for failures.

The data should include as a minimum the property `text`:

```
{
  "text": "Hello World!"
}
```

Updated code:

```
exports.webhook = functions.database.ref('/hooks/{hookId}').onWrite(event => {
  return request({
    uri: WEBHOOK_URL,
    method: 'POST',
    headers: headers,
    body: event.data.val(), // <= CHANGED
    json: true, // <= ADDED
    resolveWithFullResponse: true
  }).then(response => {
    if (response.statusCode >= 400) {
      throw new Error(`HTTP Error: ${response.statusCode}`);
    }
    console.log('SUCCESS! Posted', event.data.ref);
  })
  .catch(err => { // <= ADDED
    console.log('FAILED err=', err);
  });
});
```

Comment: So, I replaced body:event.data.val() and added json:true. 
Still i get the below error
StatusCodeError: 400 - invalid_payload
    at new StatusCodeError (/user_code/node_modules/request-promise/lib/errors.js:26:15)
    at Request.RP$callback [as _callback] (/user_code/node_modules/request-promise/lib/rp.js:68:32)
    at Request.self.callback (/user_code/node_modules/request-promise/node_modules/request/request.js:188:22)

Comment: See my update.  I was just able to successfully send a message using that code and data of `{ "text": "Hello World" }`.  I suspect you are getting "invalid payload" because your data does not contain `text` property.